# How to expose paging data in REST export views

Tags: views, paging, 8

How to allow views to export paging data along with entities?

I can set pager, and it works of course, for example my_view?page=1
displays something like

```
[ 
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

but I only get list of filtered or paginated entities, and I would like to include paging information, something like

```
[ 
  paging_info: [
    total: 4,
    per_page: 2,
    current_page: 1,
    ...
  ],
  data: [
    {...},
    {...}
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Enable pager Exposed option "Allow user to control the number of items displayed in this view" in rest display, then build custom module with views style plugin - to return results and pager data, and set in rest display

short code from custom style plugin:

```
$ret = $this->serializer->serialize(
 [
   'results' => $rows,
   'pager' => [
     'count' => $count,
     'pages' => $pages,
     'items_per_page' => $items_per_page,
     'current_page' => $current_page,
   ]
 ],
 $content_type
);
```

full code in gist: https://gist.github.com/svetlio/79f3c32667b21d89ed03cdb660308668

thanks to Dan's post here: https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/8-insights-and-useful-snippets-d8-rest-module

Answer (score 0):

So as a temp solution I ended up creating custom route which executes the view I want and returns JSON response. So in a controller method I have something like this

```
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView('MY_VIEW_NAME');
//...
$view->executeDisplay('MY_VIEW_DISPLAY_NAME');

$rendered = $view->render();
$json = $rendered['#markup']->jsonSerialize();
$data = json_decode($json);

$pager = [
  'total_rows' => $view->total_rows,
  //...
];

return new JsonResponse([$pager, $data]);
```

I wont mark this as an answer because I'm sure there is better way of getting desired output.